# I can skip contact information in Shopify checkout, but am unable to opt-out marketing beforehand, which doesn't seem compliant. What can I do?

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-api, storefront, shopify-storefront-api

I'm currently passing an [email](https://shopify.dev/api/storefront/reference/checkouts/checkoutemailupdatev2) & [shipping address](https://shopify.dev/api/storefront/reference/checkouts/checkoutshippingaddressupdatev2) to Shopify's checkout since Shopify doesn't support multiple destinations. So to avoid confusion I use our company's address and prefill the address, while the actual destination addresses show up as a custom attribute of each line item.

[image: Example of address in the line item custom attribute]

This isn't ideal, but its the best we can do with Shopify at the moment, eCommerce isn't very well built for gift giving.

After clicking checkout in the cart on our storefront, they are taken straight to the shipping method selection.

However I noticed a pretty bad problem with this solution, the opt-in marketing **is true by default**. Since the opt-in is on the first step which we skipped, the customer never sees the prompt and is not aware they will be signed up for marketing emails. I'm no lawyer but that doesn't sound very compliant.

I've dug through the Storefront API documentation and can't find any way to set `buyer_accepts_marketing` in checkout.

It confuses me a bit why I can set both the email and shipping address in checkout, which skips the first step, but I can't set the marketing opt-in.

Is there any workaround for setting `buyer_accepts_marketing` before grabbing the checkout weburl?

Comment: Post on the shopify community forum and you might responses from shopify staff. Sometimes, their docs miss a few details about certain fields.